# Show the same divs on different pages in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have, for example, 3 different pages. All pages should have a menu div, a logo div and a footer div. All divs should be the same on every page.

Is there any way to develop only one page and when I make a change on that page, this change should appear on every other page, in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). As well as that MSDN page, you can view more tutorials on the official [ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a master page then you get that same effect.  Or you can use user controls and then include them in all 3 pages.